# Issue in GridView in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am showing images on gridview. it works fine if i have 4,8,12,16 and so on images but when i have images more or less then 4,8,12 then i cant click on them. if i have 6 images then i can click on 4 images but i cant click on 5th and 6th image.

this is my tableview code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView_p cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *hlCellID = @"hlCellID";

    UITableViewCell *hlcell = [tableView_p dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:hlCellID];
    if(hlcell == nil) {
        hlcell =  [[[UITableViewCell alloc] 
                    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:hlCellID] autorelease];
        hlcell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        hlcell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    int section = indexPath.section;
    NSMutableArray *sectionItems = [sections objectAtIndex:section];

    int n = [sectionItems count];
    int i=0,i1=0; 

    while(i<n){
        int yy = 4 +i1*74;
        int j=0;
        for(j=0; j<4;j++){

            if (i>=n) break;
            NSLog(@"Counter i %d , j %d , n %d ",i,j, n);
            Item *item = [sectionItems objectAtIndex:i];

            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(16+75*j, yy, 65, 65);
            UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
            [button setFrame:rect];
            //UIImage *buttonImageNormal=[UIImage imageNamed:item.image];
            UIImage *buttonImageNormal = item.savedImage;
            [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];

            NSString *tagValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d", indexPath.section+1, i];
            button.tag = [tagValue intValue];
            //NSLog(@"....tag....%d", button.tag);

            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
            [button release];

            /*UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((75*j)-4, yy+44, 80, 12)] autorelease];
             label.text = item.title;
             label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
             label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
             label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
             label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT" size:12]; 
             [hlcell.contentView addSubview:label];
             */
            i++;
        }
        i1 = i1+1;
    }
    return hlcell;
}
```

[image]

```
- (void)loadView {

    [super loadView];
    sections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    imagesPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int s=0;s<1;s++) { // 4 sections
        sectionPattern = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


        for(int i=0;i<9+3;i++) {  // 12 items in each section 
            NSLog(@"Loop First %d",i);
           //Here i am allocating images to sectionPattern and than in sections and using it later in above code
            NSLog(@"Loop OUt %d",i);
        }
        [sections addObject:sectionPattern];

    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to say without more of your code, but you should make sure that you are returning a correct value in `- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Comment: I hace edited my question can u help me now. i am returning 1 in numberOfRowInsection.

Comment: This should return the number of rows you have in the table and this would be 3 for what is on your screenshot. You should divide the total number of items you have (9 on the screenshot) and divide by how many items per row you need (4) and add 1 if there is any rest from the division. Hope it makes sense:) and remember to do it fer each section separately if needed